# Light speed engine for space travel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

A Tesla coil that generates lightning but it sends it in all directions. Would channeling the bolts into a tube with a opposing magnetic field so all the lightning bolts are fused into a single stream of plasma create thrust?
NASA is looking for a means to build a light speed engine. Lightning travels at the speed of light and if that energy could be contained to deliver thrust.
If a small craft could travel through the vacuum of space at lightning speed, how long would it take to reach Mars without a Moon trajectory? For that matter to the other planets in our solar system?

Comment: You would then need batteries or something to power the engine, which are generally not desirable to take as a primary fuel source on a space shuttle.

Answer (score 1):

> Lightning travels at the speed of light

No it does not.

Lightning is simply a stream of charged particles.  There are no massless charged particles and only massless particles travel at the speed of light.

So what you're describing is, at best, an [ion thrust engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster).